# How to visualize comparison graph in java?

Tags: java, data-structures

I have two instances of data structure in my code:

```
public List<LatencyBulk> tillOneSecondBulks;
public List<LatencyBulk> tillFiveSecondBulks;
public LatencyBulk moreThanFiveSecondBulks;
```

How can I visualize these two instances comparison ?

I thought maybe a columns graph (excel site) or a table with "delta" column.

```
*         -             
*  -      -       -      
*  -    * -       -    * -

col1    col2   col3    col4
```

But I don't which external lib can help

Comment: What kind of graph are you comparing? A Java object graph or a "graph" data structure you created? Depending on the graph, comparing can be a hard problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism

Comment: added the data structure that i forgot to add

Comment: I think you should use R instead of Java(if you can choose your programming language to achieve this)

Comment: what are the columns for? what is the meaning of * and -? What is LatencyBulk? What do you actually want to get out of the visualization?

Comment: The table is for easy watching the count of each column.

Comment: `LatencyBulk` doesn't mater, the design don't rely on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's graph plotting you are looking for, you could take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851035/i-am-looking-for-a-plotting-library-for-java

Answer (score 0):

You could try https://code.google.com/p/deep-equals/, but as far as I know it won't give you diffs.